Merge one feature class into another and only filling one specific column using ArcGIS
I have a feature class with many line elements and a column called 'type', I want to merge this feature class with another empty feature class in which there are a number of empty columns. In this empty feature class there is a column called 'object type' I want the text from the 'type' column to be filled into this new layers 'object type' column.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. What you are describing isn't a "merge", it's a Join, over which you could Calculate the value. There's probably a half-dozen ways to accomplish this, so please research your options, make an attempt, and if that doesn't succeed, then you'll have a problem to solve which you can document as an [Edit] to this Question.

I don't want to join, since I also want the whole shape of the line to be added to the empty table.

Aditionally, the empty feature class has a drop-down menu for each column I want to preserve if possible. @Vince

So an Append, with field mapping, after you set up the domain?

I used the Append tool with the setting Maintain Attachments in the environments setting of the tool checked on so I preserved the domains in the empty feature class and made sure that in both feature classes there was a column with the same name.
